# Zookeeper on Dataproc

Tags: apache-zookeeper, google-cloud-dataproc

I could use an advice about setting up Zookeeper ensamble on Dataproc.
The scenario at hand is a project that will have 3 long running Dataproc clusters, and many ephemeral clusters that will be dynamically created per job.

I would like to have a quorum of at least 7 zookeepers but haven't found any documentation on how to get it done.

I know that I can add Zookeeper component to each Dataproc cluster, but how can I create an ensamble comprised of several clusters?

Comment: Please attach code and/or be more specific. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you can activate Zookeeper on Dataproc with help of [Zookeeper component](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/zookeeper).

Each Dataproc cluster with Zookeepr component will initialize an independent 3-node Zookeeper cluster.

If you want to configure a single Zookeeper cluster that spans multiple Dataproc clusters then you need to do this manually. It should be possible to orchestrate Zookeeper nodes on multiple Dataproc clusters in a single Zookeeper cluster using [Dataproc cluster properties](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties) with `zookeeper:` prefix.